# Mobile Website - Viewport depending on device-width

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mobile, viewport

I have a mobile website and a little problem with the Viewport meta tag in the -Part.

My code:

```
<meta id="testViewport" name="viewport" content="width=640">
```

It is working fine on an iPhone 4s but on the iPad 2, it doesn't work properly. I want the viewport to be set as the width of the users hardware. Is there a way to achieve it or do I have to read out the model type and set the Viewport with a switch or if code?

Thanks in advance.

Niels

edit:

Here's my CSS. What I want to achieve: let the site be displayed in the device-width. but if the display-size is smaller than 640px, then it should change the viewport to 640px. Not working on iOS 7.0, Safari:

```
@viewport { 
    width: device-width;    
}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) {
   @viewport {
     width: 640px;
   }
}
```

edit#2:

Fixed it using JS in the  of the index.html:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script>
    if (window.innerWidth < 640){
    var vp = document.getElementById('viewport');
    vp.setAttribute('content', 'width=640');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting `content="width=640"` try this one `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

**UPDATE:**

To serve high-res images / change zooming for retina devices with your css you could use something like this:

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

Comment: Hi. I tried it but the problem is, that the actual resolution for the iPhone 4S is 960x640, while the device-width is still 320. This is caused because of the retina displays. And a site optimized for 640px looks horrible on 320px.

Comment: You could use mediaquerys in your css to detect the dpi of the device and if it has the dpi of retina devices then use images that are 2x the size of the smaller one.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work. I don't have images anyway, only DIVs. The problem is, that they are build to show properly from a width of 640 to up to 1560px (so it's a variable size) but under 640, it starts to mess up pretty bad.

Comment: In which way are they messing up? Do they just look bad cause they are too big to look good or do they float into another line? If its just that they are to big for your screen you could set `initial-scale=0.5` in the meta viewport tag.

Comment: Yep. But then I have the problem, that they are zoomed-out on other devices aswell. I only want to set the initial-scale=0.5 if the device is an iPhone 4S or an iPad 3.

Comment: Then combine mediaquery for dpi and the zooming, in the mediaquery you set the zooming factor of the viewport to the scale that you want.

Comment: I didn't know, I could use it in CSS. Works perfectly fine. Thank you a lot for your effort and patience!

Comment: Okay, sorry to disturb you again. For some reason I still don't get it to work (I still had a fixed viewport size in the html, when trying out the CSS solution). I posted my CSS above. Could you take a look at it? It is not working at iOS 7.0 in Safari.

Comment: Hm... I just googled a little bit and found out that it could be that Safari doesn't support the css `@viewport` yet. I'm not sure if it still isn't implemented in iOS 7.1 Safari. Now the only thing that i could think of that would help you, is resizing everything on your site with the ´@media´ tag. I'm sorry that I didn't know that Safari doesn't support the ´@viewport´ tag.

Comment: No problem. I finally fixed it with JS:
 <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <script>
  if (window.innerWidth < 640){
  var vp = document.getElementById('viewport');
  vp.setAttribute('content', 'width=640');
  }
 </script>